# Google Big Query and Tableau

Tags: google-bigquery, tableau-api

I have several large tables in Google Big Query. Each table contain the same columns. The tables are split up by month. E.g. all_relevant_data_January, all_relevant_data_february etc.

I want to get all this data into Tableau to display in a dashboard but only call 1 month at a time using a filter or parameter. This is so the data for that month in question is only returned.

Can i create a custom sql connection in tableau that uses a parameter to call only the table i need. Eg.

Select * from
All_relevant_data_* 
Where monthyear = [month parameter]

Or am i better to dump it all in 1 table and then use a parameter? eg

Select * from 
All_relevant_data_all_months
Where monthyear = [month parameter]

If i were to do this, will it load all the data into tableau or will it only call whichever month i select in the dashboard?

I have been struggling with tabledaterange in tableau and dont know how to do this if that is an option.

Any help is greatfully received.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are interested in [wildcard tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/wildcard-tables). Most users who aren't taking advantage of [partitioned tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables) have their tables set up with suffixes such as `20170101`, `20170201`, `20170301`, etc. If this is the case for you as well, you can write a query such as:

```
SELECT * FROM `All_relevant_data_*`
WHERE _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170101' AND '20170301';
```

If your tables do have suffixes such as `January` and `February`, you can still make this approach work, e.g. by extracting the month number from the name:

```
SELECT * FROM `All_relevant_data_*`
WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM PARSE_DATE('%B', _TABLE_SUFFIX)) BETWEEN
  1 AND 3;
```

If you want a query that returns the month column in order to filter on it separately, you can use one of these modified forms:

```
-- Assumes that _TABLE_SUFFIX is e.g. 20170314
SELECT *, PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', _TABLE_SUFFIX) AS date
FROM `All_relevant_data_*`;
```

Or:

```
-- Assumes that _TABLE_SUFFIX is e.g. January
SELECT *, EXTRACT(MONTH FROM PARSE_DATE('%B', _TABLE_SUFFIX)) AS month_number
FROM `All_relevant_data_*`;
```

Comment: Thanks Elliot. How would i then select in tableau which month i need? Would this be done using a filter or parameter to reduce to amount of data coming in

Comment: I added a couple of more examples that might work for you. I'm not very familiar with Tableau, but I'm assuming that you can use one of these and add a filter either on `date` or on `month_number`, depending on which one you use.

Comment: Thank you. I shall try this later